# If L = lim_x→a f(x) exists, then |f(x)| → |L| as x → a .

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Suppose that f is a real function.

a) Prove that if $L = \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists, then $|f(x)|\to |L|$ as $x \to a$ .

Proof: Suppose that f is a real function. And suppose $L = lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists. Then by definition, this is true when given a real number $a$, in an open interval, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0 $ s.t $0 < | x - a| < \delta  $ implies $|f(x) - L| < epsilon$.

Then by the triangle inequality $|f(x) - L| <= |f(x)| - |L| < \epsilon$.

Thus $ \lim_{x\to a} |f(x)| = |L|$. Therefore $|f(x)| \to |L|$ as $x \to a$

Can anyone please help me? I am not sure if this is a correct way to prove it. 
Thank you.

Comment: The triangle inequality cannot be used to say that $|a-b|\leq |a|-|b|$.  Moreover, the inequality is not always true: if $a=0$ and $b=1$, then we have $|0-1|=1\leq -1=|0|-|1|$.

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty. If $f(x)\to k$, how could you possibly not have $|f(x)|\to |k|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use $||f(x)|-|L||\leq |f(x)-L|$ then it is immediate.
Edit: the inequality $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$ is a consequence of the triangular inequality, then you can use it. Now by the definition of the limite above, given $\epsilon$ just take the same $\delta>0$ from the limite,  then $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, but you have that by triangular inequalit that $||f(x)|-|L||\leq |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ provided $|x-a|<\delta$.

Comment: I thought we could only do it the other way around? Thus, using your statement, then lim_x→a |f(x)| = |L|. Therefore |f(x)| → |L| as x → a?

Comment: I edited, any doubt, add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Basically right. However the proof should adjust a little here:

$$\big||f(x)|-|L|\big|\le |f(x)-L|< \epsilon$$.

In fact, we always have the following inequation:

$$\big||x|\pm |y|\big|\le \big|x\pm y\big| \le |x|+|y|.$$